# Insert multiple Mysql record using Array

Tags: php, mysql

i have an array of company name, i insert each company name as separate record.below is the code

```
<input type="text" name="company_name[]">

$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];

 if($company_name)
 {
    foreach($company_name as $company)
    {
    $mycompany[] = $company;
    }
 }

$val="('".implode("'), ('",$mycompany)."')";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table`
 (`company_name`) VALUES ".$val."";
```

The above query look like this and it successfully inserted 2 records in table.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`company_name`) VALUES ('DELL'), ('IBM')
```

Now the problem is that with every company_name there is a company_code which i want to insert with each record and there is 3rd values lets suppose order_num which i also want to insert but the order_num should be same in all records,i need the query below

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`order_num`,`company_name`,`company_code`) VALUES ('123','DELL','axc89'), ('123','IBM','bxc90')
```

Comment: where company code goes from?

Comment: and why do you need company code and name? can't it be only code?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel i edit my code plz check it, and i m making a very complex online order form so thats y i need both company_code & order_num

Comment: WHERE DO YOU GET THE COMPANY CODE?

Comment: get comapny code same as company name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, at last you endeavored to produce something understandable

1) This this code is **absolutely useless**:

```
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];

 if($company_name)
 {
    foreach($company_name as $company)
    {
    $mycompany[] = $company;
    }
 }
```

as $mycompany being an exact duplicate of $company_name

2) To get your "very complex" query

```
foreach($_POST['company_name'] as $key => $value)
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company_code'][$key]);
    $mycompany[] = "(123,'$name','$code')";
}
$sql  = "INSERT INTO `table` (order_num,company_name,company_code) VALUES ";
$sql .= implode(",",$mycompany);
```

Comment: Not my problem.`"get comapny code same as company name"` - so I did.

Comment: <input type="text" name="company_name[]">
<input type="text" name="company_code[]">
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
$company_code = $_POST['company_code'];

yes sure its same but i don't know y its not working

Comment: go on fix it. this is not do-my-job-for-free site. this is Q&A site. you've got the answer. go finish the job.

Comment: see if $_POST['company_code'] contains anything. if not - check the spelling.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8490/discussion-between-arif-and-col-shrapnel)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`order_num`,`company_name`,`company_code`) VALUES ('123','DELL','axc89');
INSERT INTO `table` (`order_num`,`company_name`,`company_code`) VALUES ('123','IBM','bxc90');
```

You can use an array

```
$arrray_to_be_inserted=array
(
   [0]=>array('123','DELL','axc89'),
   [1]=>array('123','IBM','bxc90')
);
```

Comment: i know the query but i want it through php code like i did for 1 record, now i need it for inserting 3 records

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing value to a new variable in foreach , try to access as $key and $value, try this and see if it can help you

```
<?php

$company_name = array("DEL","IBM");
$company_code = array("1","2");
$order_num = array("4","5");

if($company_name)
 {
foreach($company_name as $key => $value)
{
    $mycompany[] = $value;
    $mycompanycode[] = $company_code[$key];
    $myordernum[] = $order_num[$key];
}
}
```

?>

Just make sure names and their values are corresponding to each other .

Comment: explain the reason for 1 down